# Google Maps not displaying in release build

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm getting this error: Failed to connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null}

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have two SHA-1 fingerprints (one from debug keystore, one from the release keystore) in the Android app within the Google API's console.

The map displays fine in debug mode however.

Basically I did everything in this document so far:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#get_an_android_certificate_and_the_google_maps_api_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's working in the debug version and not the release version it may be that you forgot to change the API key in your manifest file. Make sure that the API key you're using in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file is the same one that is associated with the Google Developer's Console that corresponds with the **Release** version of your application and not the debug version.

This is the line in your manifest that I'm referring to:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

Comment: Wait you need to have two android applications? I thought you just had to generate the debug and release fingerprints and have them both registered in the android application... am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: Apparently you need two android applications, one for debug and the other for release.

Comment: Sorry for the late response - hopefully [this SO post will better explain the difference between debug and release versions of your app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880106/what-is-difference-between-debug-keystore-and-release-keystore-in-android)