# Android: google maps only works by usb install

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a strange bug. I have an app with Google maps in it. When I install the app over Android Studio with USB it works. But when I generate a signed APK and install it - it doesnt work.

Do you know why?

UPDATE:
The install works but I cannot see a map. Its just gray.

Comment: Define doesn't work.  Doesn't install?  Doesn't run?  Crashes on run-  if so what exception?

Comment: Im guessing you are not using a release api key

Comment: @GabeSechan I update my question.

Comment: Where did you store your api key? Make sure it is a release api key

Answer (score 1):

When you install your app via usb you use a debug keystore. When you generate a signed apk, a 'real' keystore is used: 
[What is difference between 'debug.keystore' and 'release.keystore' in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21880106/what-is-difference-between-debug-keystore-and-release-keystore-in-android)

You maps API key that you generated in the Google developer console is tied to one keystore / its SHA1, probably your debug one. 
You have to get an API key tied to your release keystore / it's SHA1.

Also see: [Google map v2 doesn't work in play store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761673/google-map-v2-doesnt-work-in-play-store/18761792#18761792)

Comment: Please just vote to close as duplicate instead of posting almost the same answer twice

Comment: @TimCastelijns Yeah, you're right about that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your google developer console and add the SHA1 Key for your developer key that you used to generate the signed apk

if you don't know how to get the SHA1 , you can search for it or:
let the app crash you can find the SHA1 in the error in the cat logs, the maps will complain about missing this fingerprint